# Parsing of nested JSON to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nsdictionary

I want to extract the values of "lat" and "lng" from JSON after parsing it to NSDictionary in objective C.How to I parse it ??

```
html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.4994796,
               "lng" : -0.1248094
            }
         },
         "id" : "f617d7c9e65e415fb39d4a0ae47dbb71f209d409",
         "place_id" : "ChIJK0O8dMQEdkgRLApeea2WlHk",
         "reference" : "CoQBcgAAAK8Oa0l7zRS1fqb83aJiHWadP3bh27CPVDILMBR7zA3CqEbR2pEro3O7sObQCoTIL7jP6bG_YL2-nCGzUlvIcyuG7HHrvCwakEjrbEImDp2VRkAbBbxUNz3V0mqUyFBFon_6G5pF_n4ovZ1fqaBhEPQ3lXbzGOJAwaOfhtKEda9mEhANy9NmIP8nHASNqiRIe-J_GhQR5WvFJnSbh23-30v2ScxAAuMT1Q"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.5058337,
               "lng" : -0.1167623
            }
         },
         "id" : "ed60145ed3bbef5036f13fcdb67bae99ce970efd",
         "place_id" : "ChIJT5N73bcEdkgRRRNgF3S7uwU",
         "reference" : "CnRwAAAA_SvSiE9sjpnqkBCOWiScw4ih5qUGPbWrBG_mYmlJhZJVHREKsV9cVKXbS5iZZyQiebmdLzqPbH37itffgIwv8Dpucbk80BfPxmhMRPYDOC3HIzdho9ystp8wqEgUoGmRjIFDDzhDa0jY_sQTIfWtDhIQFhL6SKjC7K8nNbK8YqCZpRoU0Y0OWpDNfiCpzP8z-5bj2PJgEv8"
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below

```
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in parentDictionary[@"results"]){
   NSDictionary *location=dictionary[@"geometry"][@"location"];
   NSLog(@"Lat = %f, Lng = %f",[location[@"lat"] floatValue],[location[@"lng"] floatValue]);
}
```

Cheers.